# Android: How can I set value of SeekBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-seekbar

I want to set my `SeekBar` value but problem is that I set my `SeekBar` and `TextView` Views into an `inflater` method in Slidemenu which don't have any `onCreate` Method so I am not able to reference SeekBar using `findViewById`. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is layout fragment_budget_filter.xml file:

```
 <TextView

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rs. 5L"
    android:id="@+id/max_budget"
/>

<SeekBar

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/budget_max_seekbar"
  />
```

and my Java file look like this:

```
 public class BudgetFragment extends Fragment { 
public BudgetFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget_filter, container, false);
    return rootView;
 }  
}
```

How can I call this following method in above java file?

```
 public class AndroidSeekBar{

// declare text objects variables
private SeekBar PRICEbar; 
private TextView SeekValue;
private TextView PRICEtextProgress,DISTANCEtextProgress, RATINGtextProgress;

public AndroidSeekBar(SeekBar id1, TextView textid){

    PRICEbar = id1; // make seekbar object
    SeekValue = textid;
    int progress = PRICEbar.getProgress();
   //        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
    PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

           @Override 
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
             boolean fromUser) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            SeekValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 
           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           } 
               }); 
           } 
 }
```

Comment: You can still use `findViewById`. In `onCreateView` in your `Fragment` just do `rootView.findViewById(R.id.budget_max_seekbar)`

Comment: Hi sahil,Please elaborate more your question. So that we can help you out. In fact you can pass fragment reference to AndroidSeekBar like seekbar and textview and call the fragment methods.

Comment: May be you want something like this: PRICEbar.setProgress(value);

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call this following method in above java file?

In [`onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) you can still use [`findViewById(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)). The following will call the constructor you want:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_budget_filter, container, false);

...

SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.budget_max_seekbar);
TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.max_budget);
AndroidSeekBar yourSeekBar = new AndroidSeekBar(seekBar, textView);

...

return rootView;
```